# How should I disconnect my gas stove?

Tags: safety, natural-gas, shutoff

We want to replace our natural gas stove with an electric stove. I've never worked with gas lines before, and the installers who will deliver the electric stove won't disconnect the gas stove for us. When I go to disconnect the stove, are there steps I should do in a particular order?

The gas line from the (outdoors) meter goes straight into the garage for the furnace and water heater. Right before entering the garage it tees off to another line for the kitchen, and there's a shutoff valve for that kitchen line only (I suspect the kitchen line was added about 5-6 years ago when a previous owner remodeled the kitchen; the house itself is about 30 years old in a large cookie-cutter neighborhood). The kitchen line runs around the outside of the house, and is probably about 80-100 feet long. Then there's a shutoff valve inside the kitchen where the stove connects to the gas line.

When I disconnect the stove, does it matter which order I shut off the two valves (inside; and where the kitchen line starts outside)? Should the stove be running when I start closing valves?

Once both valves are off and I disconnect the flexible hose to the stove, I'll cap the line where I disconnected the stove, too.

Comment: Have you contacted the gas company?  They might come out and disconnect it for you and then check for leaks from your valves.

Comment: it may be illegal in your area for you to work on the gas line ... also, if you do the work and something goes wrong, then the insurance company may reject your claim

Comment: Can you give a picture of the back of the stove? Generally there is a shut off right before the stove and a flexible gas line from it to the stove. If so, you just shut off the gas at this point and remove the flexible line to the stove and leave it off.

Comment: I would still put a cap on after the valve . You never know when in the future a child or a fool will turn the valve to see what happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very simple task as long as you are legally allowed to disconnect the stove (many places allow you to install your own appliances).  I think that people are unreasonably afraid of "working on gas", but you're not actually working on something - you're turning off a valve.

So, turn off the valve that leads to the kitchen, then turn off the valve going to the stove.  Disconnect the flex line from the wall and the stove so you can take it with you to get a cap to put over the valve.  Once you have the correct size cap, tighten it onto the end of the valve and you're done.  If you smell any gas after the initial disconnect, then call in someone to inspect it, but that would mean that you just happen to have *two* defective gas valves *and* you did a bad job putting the safety cap on the valve.

Answer (score 2):

Considering the fact that you've never worked with gas lines, contact the gas company. They will probably come out and disconnect it for you and then check for leaks from your valves.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1. Call the gas co. service to do it for you.
Step 2. Sleep well knowing you won't die in your sleep or blow your house to kingdom come.

This just is not something you want to take any chances with just to save $50. Jack is right.

Comment: Just to keep this as widely applicable as possible, in the UK you would not call the gas company, but a qualified gas engineer (probably operating as a "Heating and Plumbing" company).  However the overall conclusion "do not DIY" is correct.

Comment: The OP called their utility, and the utility told them to DIY this job....

Comment: The utility person may have been correct in saying the utility does not do this. However, there were dead wrong about it being DIY. I'm no lawyer, but  would venture that they could be liable if the homeowner follows their advice and something bad happens.